# Can you "expenses-in-a-corp V. standard deduction" in the USA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, expenses, s-corporation, deduction

This seems like a "too good to be true" tax dodge in the USA milieu.

Is it correct?

- Sally is a graphic designer married with a typical family. She gets $100,000 in 2017 as 1099 income.
- She buys a Graphics Monitor in 2017 for $1000.  We'll say, it is genuinely and absolutely a true and honest deductible expense for her work/clients. *(She bought it for "a particular job" so the entire amount is deductible at once.)*
- She files her taxes. She gets the "standard deduction" of $1**2**,700. So it's completely pointless itemizing deductions.
- In short she gets $12,700 deductions.

She goes back in time and tries this:

- She has an S-Corp (or LLC as an S-Corp). It is paid the $100,000 in 2017.
- The monitor is a deduction, a cost, for the S-Corp. Which thus profits $99,000 in 2017.
- Sally gets $99,000 income, and takes the standard deduction of $12,700.
- In short she gets $1**3**,700 "deductions".

This appears to be an absolutely correct way to save 1000- in taxable income.

Any deductions (more precisely: **"costs"**) totaling under 12700 in situation "A" are totally wasted; in situation "B" you get them.

It seems too good to be true - am I correct?

---

Just a clarification for any future googlers, in fact *I am not correct*. IE, there is *no* advantage, you "get" the $1000 either way. HartCO explains it below!

Comment: Business expenses (deductions) offset business income, nothing to do with itemized deductions.

Comment: OK - so in "A", Sally can NOT in any way take advantage of the $1000 - is that correct?  Teach me

Comment: I think what Hart means is that business expenses are deducted _separately_ from personal expenses, so one can deduct business expenses _and_ take the full standard deduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Business expenses (deductions) offset business income, so no matter which type of pass-through business entity she is using (Sole proprietorship,LLC,S-Corp,Partnership), the expenses will offset her business revenue. She's taxed on the profit from her business, not the revenue.

In both cases, she only has $99,000 in business income reported in the income section of the 1040, and nothing further down on her tax return changes that. The only tax-disadvantage she faces filing as a sole-proprietor (example 1) is that she might pay more self-employment tax than if she has an S-Corp.

Comment: Wait - in the first example, Sally's not using *any* sort of business entity - right?

Comment: I get it: even if you just file individually with no "corp" aspect at all - you still "first" calculate any business costs. OK!  So in short my example was completely wrong, that's the answer.  Awesome!!!

Comment: @Fattie Yeah the default is 'sole-proprietorship' if you have 1099 income.

Answer (score 1):

It goes on Schedule C, which is business profit/loss, and has no impact on itemized deductions.